# How to load image and buttons correctly when switching from portrait mode to landscape mode in ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios-simulator, landscape-portrait

I have developed a iPAD app which looks good in portrait mode but when I rotate the screen to landscape(that is rotate left or right) on emulator.Image is not loading properly and also buttons(8 buttons, 2overlapping with another 2) are overlapping.How can I correct this?

Note: I'm loading my 1st screen image as back ground image in "ViewDidLoad" Method.Also,using xcode 4.4 and 4.6 for my development.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to use autolayout for that.

Check this guide:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: Seems to be helhpful..I'll try.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to play with these methods:

```
- (void)updateLayoutForNewOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation{
if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    // Portrait
}
else{

    //Landscape
}}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   [self updateLayoutForNewOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
      [self updateLayoutForNewOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];}
```

In updateLayoutForNewOrientation method you have to play with the bounds of your components according Orientation.

Comment: "updateLayoutForNewOrientation" is this method provided by apple or user define...Intelisence is not showing this nethod.Any idea? I'm using xcode 4.6.

Comment: It is a user defined method so you can call this whatever you want.